# A probability problem on finding expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the random variable $X$ is $N(\mu,1)$, show that the random variable $Y=\frac{1-\Phi(X)}{\phi({X})}$, where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denote the cdf and pdf of $N(0,1)$, respectively has mean value $\frac{1}{\mu}$. How to proceed in this problem ?

Comment: The density of $X$ is $\phi(x-\mu)$. What happens if you use [LOTUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and integrate by parts where needed?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I thought that initially, but due to long calculation I thought there might be some easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOTUS should be used and then an interchange of the limits of integration.

$$Y=\frac{1-\Phi(X)}{\phi({X})} = g(X) \Rightarrow E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)g(x) dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x-\mu)\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi({x})} dx$$

Calculate explicitly

$$\phi(x-\mu) = \phi(x) \cdot \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \cdot \exp\left \{-\frac 12 \mu^2\right \}$$

Then

$$E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \cdot \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \cdot \exp\left \{-\frac 12 \mu^2\right \}\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi({x})} dx  $$

$$=  \exp\left \{-\frac 12 \mu^2\right \}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \left[1-\Phi(x)\right]dx=   \exp\left \{-\frac 12 \mu^2\right \}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \Phi(-x)dx $$

We have
$$I_x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \Phi(-x)dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \int_{-\infty}^{-x}\phi(z)dzdx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{-x} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \phi(z)dzdx $$

where $z$ is a dummy variable of integration.

Interchange the limits of integration from
\begin{matrix}
-\infty \le x \le \infty\\
-\infty \le z \le -  x
\end{matrix}

to

\begin{matrix}
-\infty \le z \le \infty\\
-\infty \le x \le -  z
\end{matrix}

Then
$$I_x  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{-z} \exp\left \{\mu x\right\} \phi(z)dxdz =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(z) \Big[\frac {1}{\mu}\exp\left \{\mu x\right\}\Big |_{-\infty}^{-z}\Big]dz$$

$$ =  \frac {1}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left \{-\mu z\right\}\phi(z) dz $$

The integral is now the moment generating function in $-\mu$ of a standard normal random variable $Z$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left \{-\mu z\right\}\phi(z) dz = \text {MGF}_Z(-\mu) = \exp\left\{\frac 12 (-\mu)^2 \right\}= \exp\left\{\frac 12 \mu^2 \right\}$$

So

$$ I_x = \frac {1}{\mu}\exp\left\{\frac 12 \mu^2 \right\} \Rightarrow E(Y) = \exp\left \{-\frac 12 \mu^2\right \}\frac {1}{\mu}\exp\left\{\frac 12 \mu^2 \right\} = \frac {1}{\mu} $$

Comment: +1 I think that some further simplification would be achieved by noting that $$Y = \frac{\Phi(-X)}{\phi(X)}=\frac{\Phi(-X)}{\phi(-X)} = \frac{\Phi(Z)}{\phi(Z)}$$ where $\Z = -X \sim N(-\mu, 1)$.

Comment: How is this evaluated ? Because we don't have any knowledge of whether $\mu >0$ or not ??$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(z) \Big[\frac {1}{\mu}\exp\left \{\mu x\right\}\Big |_{-\infty}^{-z}\Big]dz$$

Comment: @prasenjit The OP's question itself has no meaning if $\mu=0$. Granted, it should have been stated as an assumption in the question, that $\mu\neq 0$, but I believe it is silently implied. To examine the same problem with $\mu=0$, other approaches are available.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: thanks for working out such long calculation and typing it here.

Comment: You're welcome. For the case $\mu=0$ we immediately have $E(Y) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(-x)dx$, which diverges, i.e. the expected value does not exist.